# How to update scrollbar when using Jetpack's Inifnite Scroller?

Tags: jquery, css

for the last couple of days, I have been trying to have a custom scrollbar (jquery+css) while using Jetpack's infinite scroller.

What I want is to get rid off the standard scrollbar and use a custom one for my content. I have tried a couple and most of them have an update function that I need to insert somewhere into Jetpack's Infinite scroller (js) so when it loads the content, the custom scrollbar gets updated and it resizes itself.

The problem is that I have no idea where to insert this update function. Can someone please help me?

I wont post any code because they are all pretty much the same. Anyways, if for some reason, you do need to see it, you can check out this one at: https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution at Jetpack's website, http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/

I just needed to insert the custom scrollbar's update function inside this function provided by jetpack's infinite scroll.

"**JavaScript Events**

Inevitably, there are situations in a theme that require some JavaScript interaction after posts are added. One such example is in a theme that uses jQuery Masonry and needs to trigger that library to position the additional posts. Recognizing this need, we trigger an event after posts are appended. To make use of this event, simply catch the post-load event when it fires on document.body:"

```
( function( $ ) {
    $( document.body ).on( 'post-load', function () {
        // New posts have been added to the page.
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```